# inner merge dataFrame with identical column names and apply aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to inner merge two dataFrames that both have some columns with same name. On the columns with same name, I don't want a new column with a suffix in merged dataFrame, but instead want to group them together and apply aggregate function (in this example, sum)

have:

d1:

```
      col1
0       1
1       2
```

d2:

```
      col1
0       3
2       5
```

with `pd.merge(d1, d2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)`

get:

```
     col1_x   col1_y
0       1       3
```

but want:

```
      col1
0       4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
print (d1)
   col1  col3
0     1     6
1     2     3
print (d2)
   col1  col2
0     3     2
2     5     4
```

Your solution - add [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by splitted columns names and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.merge(d1, d2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)

df = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).sum()
#alternative
#df = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).sum()
```

Here si simplier use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) by `join='inner'` with `sum` by columns:

```
df = pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1, join='inner').sum(level=0, axis=1)
print (df)
   col1  col3  col2
0     4     6     2
```

Comment: my bad but I oversimplified my case, first method gives me trouble since my columns are PeriodIndex therefore 'split' throws an error. I also have multiIndex (multiple level) so your seconds suggestion throws an exception due to `axis=1` . My brute-force solution right now is to convert PeriodIndex to strings and use 1st suggestion.

Comment: @DRmo - What is `print (d1.columns)` ?

Comment: @DRmo - Is possible use `df = df.groupby(lambda x: str(x).split('_')[0], axis=1).sum()` with `PeriodIndex` ?